# Virus file systems.php on my server?

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, webserver, virus

I found a file `systems.php` on my webserver that neither I - as user - placed there, nor my webserver provider has placed in there. I viewed the file, it only contains one `preg_replace()` statement with an extremly long `$replacement` part, which seems to be somehow encoded.

```
preg_replace("/.*/e","\x28\x65\...\x29\x29\x3B",".");
```

If I interpret this statement correctly, it would mean that basically everything shall be replaced be the `$replacement` part (which might be encrypted/encoded virus injection stuff).

I have [uploaded the whole code as pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/Nem11Lqa). Someone has an idea in what way the code is encrypted/how it can be decrypted in order to assess the grade of compromisation of my server?

## Update

This might be the attack vector:

> So after some digging, we found that this script was planted using a vulnerability in the Uploadify jQuery library. The library's existence was discovered by the attacker through google. [<sup>source</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524470/trouble-decoding-a-php-virus-planted-on-my-server?rq=1#comment18516175_13524501)

Comment: Guessing it is an obfuscated virus. If it's on your webserver and you (or your host) didn't put it there, it is really unlikely to belong there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this giant regex work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328235/how-does-this-giant-regex-work)

Comment: Do you or one of the server administrators use the FileZilla FTP client? Given the way this tool stores passwords, it's often targeted by malware which then uploads backdoors like this to your servers. Change all your passwords for that server and install a decent FTP client. If it isn't FileZilla, you may have an upload script that's faulty. Change all passwords nonetheless, or better even reinstall the entire system as you don't know what's been compromised.

Comment: @CodeCaster No, noone using FileZilla. But I've changed all passwords after finding this file. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Fluffeh Yeah, thought so, too. That's why I asked here to get more information. Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unhexxing the shellcode shows it's executing `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(huge string));`

I changed this `eval` to an `echo` and the full output is on pastebin here:

http://pastebin.com/t1iZ5LQ8

I haven't looked much further into this but it certainly seems dodgy. Just thought I'd do some of the legwork for anyone interested in looking at it further

### EDIT

Little bit more detailed look, it appears to allow an attacker to upload files to your server, and take a dump of any databases on the box

Comment: Thanks for your help on decrypting/decoding it. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's look like a Shellcode, which can be disastrous for your server, shellcode executed by the CPU can give access to a shell or shuch of things.
For more informations about shellcodes here's a good article :

http://www.vividmachines.com/shellcode/shellcode.html

This upload may hide a possible exploit on your server which grant access to upload or write data into, try to check your logs to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll inform my provider about it.